# Why am I getting strange symbols ">>>>" in front of the bootstrap table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am creating a table in bootstrap to display list of Orders for a particular Customer. I am getting strange symbols ahead of my bootstrap table.See below image for reference.

[image]

The code of bootstrap table

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h1>Order Infomration</h1>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <th>Order Id</th>
                    <th>Created Date</th>
                    <th>Order Status</th>
                    <th>Order Total</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="order" items="${orderList}">>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href=""><c:out value="${order.orderId}" /></a></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${order.createdDate}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${order.orderStatus}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="Rs.${order.orderTotal}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the reason for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra closing angle brace at the end of your `forEach` loop.

```
<c:forEach var="order" items="${orderList}">>
```

Use this,

```
<c:forEach var="order" items="${orderList}">
```

It is because of your `forEach` that you are using. The number of times your `forEach` loop executes the extra `>` will be generated and shows on the output.

Just delete the extra `>` from your `forEach` loop.

The number of times your `forEach` loop executes, the `>` are generated. Its a written mistake. Just remove it and gets the output that you wanted.